# kill one instance of ffserver out of multiple using specific configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, ffserver

I have two instances of ffserver running both using different configuration file kept at different path.
I want to kill one of them using a script.
when i write following command :

```
    ps -ef |grep ffs
```

it gives output :

```
    root      6421  6394  0 18:47 pts/11   00:00:00 /root/bin/ffserver -f /root/newff/ffserver.conf
    root      6575  6562  0 18:49 pts/11   00:00:02 /root/bin/ffserver -f /root/test/downloaded/complete/ffserver.conf
    root      8453  3720  0 19:09 pts/11   00:00:00 grep ffs
```

Now i want to kill only one .
Is there any way to kill using command name like i can give command name with kill

```
   pkill_like_command /root/bin/ffserver -f /root/newff/ffserver.conf
```

Please tell me how to do that
as simple pkill will not work.

Comment: And does it not work with `(sudo) kill -9 <pid>`?

Comment: @KiaMorot i dont have to kill it manually...but from within a script

Answer (score 0):

There is an `-f` switch that works for `pkill`, so that matching considers the full command line. You can test without killing using `pgrep` instead. So the command line would be for example (tested on Debian with procps 1:3.2.8-9):

```
pkill -f "ffserver.*/root/newff/ffserver.conf"
```

without `pkill`:

```
kill $( ps -ef | grep "ffserver.*/root/newff/ffserver.conf" | awk '{ print $2 }' )
```

Comment: maybe your version does not support the `-f` switch? alternative added